# Is there a way to perform batch update on Swift arrays?

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array of 1000+ items. Initially, the array elements have a state called `initial`.

At some point of time, I want to change the state of some items to `updated`.

If I changed the array items one by one, like iterating over the array and update their values if it met a condition, with every update I will get a callback for the array's `didSet`.

I don't want this. What I really want is to perform a batch update on the array, thus, I get a callback only once when I finish updating multiple items in the array.

Is that possible in Swift?

Comment: Update your question showing relevant code demonstrating the issue you need to solve.

Comment: `Array.map` is usually the solution.

Comment: @Sulthan I'd kind of discounted `map` because sometimes it can get complicated for these kinds of problems, and it feels like a lot of processing if the number of changes is small, but trying it out, agreed, it's a fine approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to make a copy, modify it as you like, and then assign it back. For example:

```
var xs = [1,2,3,4] {
    didSet {
        print("SET")
    }
}

var ys = xs
ys[0] = 0
ys[2] = 100

xs = ys
```

(Prints "SET" just one time.)

Before you ask: 1000 items is not a large array. Copying it this way infrequently is generally not a problem unless the stored items are themselves very large. But what if copying really does turn out to be a problem? Then you can go the unsafe route:

```
xs.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { (ptr) in
    ptr[0] = 1000
    ptr[1] = 2000
}
```

---

I'd kind of discounted `map` to solve this, but in trying to respond to Sulthan about why, I kind of talked myself out of it. You can definitely use `map`, especially given the kind of use case you were mentioning.

```
let updatedIndexes = [0, 2]
xs = xs.enumerated()
    .map { (n, value) in
        return updatedIndexes.contains(n) ? State.updated : value
}
```

Comment: Haa this is great, I used the copy way, 1000 is not a problem for copying, I meant it's bad to get a callback for every update in the 1000 element when I do not need it.
Thanks Rob, and nice to meet you at stack overflow, love your talks :)

Comment: To be honest, I would also consider making `updated` a separate variable, e.g. `var updated: Set<Int>` but it all depends on the exact use case.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to batch update an array is to pass it as an `inout` variable to the function that updates it.  Because of the *copy in - copy out* semantics of `inout`, the array will only be updated once:

```
class Foo {
    var arr: [Int] = [1,2,3,4,5] {
        didSet {
            print("SET")
        }
    }

    func batchUpdate(_ arr: inout [Int]) {
        for idx in arr.indices {
            arr[idx] *= 2
        }
    }

    func test() {
        batchUpdate(&arr)
        print(arr)
    }
}

Foo().test()
```

> ```
> SET
> [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
> ```